# How to input Variables in db.collection.aggregation()?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a function in MongoDb in which i need to input 4 variables and perform $lookup , $unwind $match etc other aggregation pipelines available in MongoDB.

Can some one tell me how can i introduce variables in my mongoDB function in correct way.

I have written the following code :

```
db.Collection-1.aggregate([
{


    }       
    $lookup:{
            from:"Collection-2",//other table name 
            localField:"ID", //name of user table field 
            foreignField:"ID",  // name of target table
            as:"RSRA" // alias  
            }

},
{
    $unwind : "$RSRA" 
},
{
    $lookup:{
            from:"Collection-3",//other table name 
            localField:"EntId", //name of user table field 
            foreignField:"EntId",  // name of target table
            as:"RSRD" // alias  
            }

},
{
    $unwind : "$RSRD"
},
```